# My kivy windows get automatic maximize button disabled

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I set up kivy app with following code

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.write()
```

but it is globally effecting other new application as well, which automatically disabled the maximize button. How could I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Config.write()` is what causes the global effect. You don't need that line if you just want to affect the current kivy process. In order to eliminate that global effect, just remove the file `.kivy/config.ini`.

Comment: Is there another wa to set the window size?

Comment: You can use `Window.size = (400, 300)`. After `from kivy.core.window  import Window`.

Comment: @john-anderson Thank you very much, I was not aware of .ini file.